# Unable to structure React Router efficiently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a reactjs project where I utilize react-router. I have multiple components to render, but not sure how to structure it. I am not getting expected results

**Components**

- *Authentication*
- *SideBar*
- *List*
- *Detail*

**App.js**

```
import ..... 
.... //some import statements
function App(){
  <BrowserRouter>
    <SideBar/>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<List/>}/>
      <Route path="/detail" element={<Detail/>}/>
      <Route path="/authentication" element={<Authentication/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
}
```

Here I have totally 4 components. The sidebar component will be common for both **Detail** and **List** component, & I don't want it to be visible for **Authentication** component.

Tried using the Outlet

**App.js**

```
import ..... 
.... //some import statements
function App(){
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Authentication/>}/>
      <Route path="/app" element={<Container/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
}
```

**Container.js**

```
import ..... 
.... //some import statements
function Container(){
    <SideBar/>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/list" element={<List/>}/>
      <Route path="/detail" element={<Detail/>}/>
    </Routes>
}
```

Now the issue is when I navigate to http:///app it is showing a blank page with sidebar, which doesn't serve a purpose.

How this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a working solution:

- The sidebar is kept in the Layout component which uses the Outlet from react-router-dom
- Having your auth route first without using the Layout
- The other two routes are "contained" within the Layout component so these pages have the Sidebar

## App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Authentication />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
              <Route path="/list" element={<List />} />
              <Route path="/detail" element={<Detail />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
export function Layout () {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
              <Sidebar />
              <Outlet />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note: Solution taken almost directly from [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209910/how-can-i-show-nav-bar-on-route-v6-only-on-a-specific-page)